# Efficient way to maintain & operate AllowList

Tags: java, json, filter

I want to maintain an AllowList and compare the incoming Json data with the AllowList and process the data which satisfies the condition. What is the efficient format to store the AllowList and efficient way to process in Java?

AllowList

```
[
    {
        "index1": "data11",
        "index2": "data21"
    },
    {
        "index1": "data12",
        "index2": "data22"
    },
    {
        "index1": "data13",
        "index2": "data23"
    }
]
```

Following is the incoming streaming data
Allowed

```
{
    "index1": "data12",
    "index2": "data22",
    "index3": "data32"
}
```

Now Allowed

```
{
    "index1": "data12",
    "index2": "data21",
    "index3": "data32"
}
```

Consider it as a comparison of List of JSON (incoming data) with list of JSON (Allow List)

Comment: I'm thinking this question does not provide enough info and is too vague to really know how to answer. It's also best, if possible, to include code that reproduces a specific problem.

Comment: My system received a stream of data in JSOn format and I want to filter and process only certain data. I have the Allow List in the above format.